# Grails Controller Custom Annotation

Tags: grails, annotations

How can I add custom annotations to Grails (2.3.11) Controller artefacts, and read them runtime? I have created the following annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String foo() default ""
}
```

And added it to the controller at class level:

```
@MyAnnotation(foo = "bar")
class MyClass {
....
}
```

I am trying to read the annotation runtime using:

```
controller.clazz.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)
```

But it is always null. If I inspect the controller's `getAnnotations()` method, it has two annotations - both from Grails (`@Enhanced` and `@GrailsPlugin`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Annotation looks ok. Show how did you add annotation to controller. Did you clean/refresh app after adding it?

Comment: Updated question with example. No. I did not clean/compile. I will try that :)

Comment: How about using *class* instead of *clazz*? Like this: `controller.class.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation)`

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa - you should infact use clazz. The "clean/compile" trick did the job.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa you should post that as an answer. it is useful :)