# Grails security without spring

Tags: grails

Can someone provide code for registering account,loggin in and out from an account but without spring?

Comment: We are not a code writing service.

Comment: You should post to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grails-dev-discuss or use http://grails.slack.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Obviously, creating User domain, Role table and join them as each User can have many roles.
2. Registration is easy - just create a form with all the needed attributes, password is hidden, of course. And **don't save it as plain text. Always encrypt password before**. Bcrypt (specially for grails) or RSA, Blowfish or Tripple DES should be the ones to use.
3. Login is also quite simple. User submits username and password. You encrypt the password and look in the database for User with such username and password hash. If there is, you *let him in*.
4. Hardest part would be securing your pages from unauthorized users. You could create your custom anotations where you check user cookie (save his session hash) and add them to controller methods. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500859/grails-controller-custom-annotation).
5. Delete what you have created and use Spring security. There is a reason it is used by so many Grails apps. And it is fairly customizable. Or [Shiro plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/shiro). Each have their own pros and cons.

Comment: for 2. use a KDF like `bcrypt`, `scrypt`, ... to store the password(hashes) instead. and for 5. adding springsecurity/shiro/... without knowing what one is doing is just as dangerous to the security of the application as writing your own without clue. it all looks nice and easy when using the plugins in grails, but if you have to diverge from them or set it up on your own, it's not trivially simple to graps how all that gears turn.

Comment: @cfrick and you think creating your own security is safer than implementing spring sec? I don't know about that. Especially if you have to ask for the code

Comment: that's not what i meant.  there are no silver bullets. setting up security and not having a clue about it, is dangerous territory -- regardless the tools, frameworks, plugins, ... one uses.